# Ionic Pro Package ios fails after build with no reason

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

After painstakingly working to get Android to build via ionic's new Ionic Pro Package service I have moved on to build my ios application. Using the same code, I am unable to build package my app and no information is provided as to why. I simply get the following at the end of the history log.

```
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Here is my full log output

```
$> cordova add platform ios
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@4.5.0
Adding ios project...
Creating Cordova project for the iOS platform:
    Path: platforms/ios
    Package: com.XXXX.XXXX
    Name: My App
iOS project created with cordova-ios@4.5.0
Discovered plugin "branch-cordova-sdk" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Failed to restore plugin "branch-cordova-sdk" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "xml2js". Please try adding it again.
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-camera" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-camera" for ios
Installing "cordova-plugin-compat" for ios
Adding cordova-plugin-camera to package.json
Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-camera" to config.xml
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-device" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-device" for ios
Adding cordova-plugin-device to package.json
Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-device" to config.xml
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-fcm" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-fcm" for ios

        Cordova FCM plugin v2.1.2 installed
        For more details visit https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm

Adding cordova-plugin-fcm to package.json
Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-fcm" to config.xml
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-file" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-file" for ios
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-compat@1.2.0" already fetched, using that version.
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-compat" already installed on ios.
Adding cordova-plugin-file to package.json
Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-file" to config.xml
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-file-transfer" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-file-transfer" for ios
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-file@4.3.3" already fetched, using that version.
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-file" already installed on ios.
Adding cordova-plugin-file-transfer to package.json
Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-file-transfer" to config.xml
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" for ios
Adding cordova-plugin-inappbrowser to package.json
Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" to config.xml
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" for ios
Adding cordova-plugin-splashscreen to package.json
Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" to config.xml
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-statusbar" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-statusbar" for ios
Adding cordova-plugin-statusbar to package.json
Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-statusbar" to config.xml
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for ios
Adding cordova-plugin-whitelist to package.json
Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-whitelist" to config.xml
Discovered plugin "cordova-sqlite-storage" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-sqlite-storage" for ios
installing external dependencies via npm
npm install of external dependencies ok
Adding cordova-sqlite-storage to package.json
Saved plugin info for "cordova-sqlite-storage" to config.xml
Discovered plugin "cordova.plugins.diagnostic" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova.plugins.diagnostic" for ios
Adding cordova.plugins.diagnostic to package.json
Saved plugin info for "cordova.plugins.diagnostic" to config.xml
Discovered plugin "ionic-plugin-deploy" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "ionic-plugin-deploy" for ios
Adding ionic-plugin-deploy to package.json
Saved plugin info for "ionic-plugin-deploy" to config.xml
Discovered plugin "ionic-plugin-keyboard" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "ionic-plugin-keyboard" for ios
Adding ionic-plugin-keyboard to package.json
Saved plugin info for "ionic-plugin-keyboard" to config.xml
--save flag or autosave detected
Saving ios@~4.5.0 into config.xml file ...
\e[91mFailed to upload ipa to storage please retry your build.\e[0m
Running after script...
$ clean-up
Cleaning up files...
Successful clean up
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

I am really unsure where to start due to the lack of debug information provided and any help would be appreciated.

The following is my ionic info

```
cli packages: (c:\Development\Code\tangent\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.10.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.10.3

global packages:

    Cordova CLI : 7.0.1

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.5.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 2.3.0

System:

    Node : v7.5.0
    npm  : 4.1.2
    OS   : Windows 10
```

Comment: I'm also having the same issue, did you have any resolution?

Comment: I am still unsure of the exact issue. I recreated my certificates and app ID and provisioning profile in the ios developer console and then uploaded these new certs (mobileProvisionProfile and .p12 files) to my ionic pro dashboard security profile. I don't know if that was the fix or if it was something else I did along the way. This worked for me. Best of luck